# How to fix "FOR loop contains no keywords." error in Robot IDE for OS

Tags: for-loop, robotframework, keyword, robotframework-ide

test result states for loop contains no keywords

I tried to make the syntax as much to the user guide as possible. It won't let me add a ':' before FOR and it says it is not necessary in the new version.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown     Close Browser
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
links
    Open Browser    http://neuromorpho.org/neuron_info.jsp?neuron_name=DD13-10-c5-1    safari
    Maximize Browser Window
    ${AllLinksCount}=    Get Element Count    //a
    Log    ${AllLinksCount}
    @{LinkItems}    Create List
    FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    ${AllLinksCount}
    \ \    Log    ${INDEX}
    \ \    ${lintext}=    Get Text    xpath= (//a) [${INDEX}]
    \ \    Log    ${lintext}
    \ \    ${linklength}    Get Length    ${lintext}
    \ \    Run Keyword If    ${linklength} >1    Append To List    ${LinkItems}    ${lintext}
    ${LinkSize}=    Get Length    ${LinkItems}
    Log    ${LinkSize}
    FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{LinkItems}
    \ \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
    Close Browser
```

I want a list of links which i can then check for response, however the error message states "FOR loop contains no keywords." help :(

Comment: What do you mean by _"It won't let me add a ':' before FOR"_? What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: look at this link - https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements

Answer (score 5):

You have to terminate the `FOR` block with the `END` command (if you changed the file)

Below is the text from the [FAQ](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/F.A.Q.) on our Wiki:

**Q:** In the newest versions of RIDE (1.7.4) and with Robot Framework 3.1.2, when I edit a Test Suite having `: FOR`, then, when is executed, appears the following error: `FOR loop contains no keywords.`. How to fix this?

**A:** Robot Framework is tolerant to the old `: FOR` format, and the test suite can be executed correctly. However, when the file is edited in RIDE, it looses the old style formatting, so you must add the terminating `END`.

Answer (score 0):

'\' is depreciated in robot 3.*

The error you are seeing is self explanatory Your For loop structure is incorrect
You are missing END cause

```
FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    ${AllLinksCount}
        Log    ${INDEX}
        ${lintext}=    Get Text    xpath= (//a) [${INDEX}]
        Log    ${lintext}
        ${linklength}    Get Length    ${lintext}
        Run Keyword If    ${linklength} >1    Append To List    ${LinkItems}    ${lintext}
END
${LinkSize}=    Get Length    ${LinkItems}
Log    ${LinkSize}
FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{LinkItems}
       Log    ${ELEMENT}
END
```

Answer (score 0):

So it should work.

```
:FOR                  ${INDEX}             IN RANGE           1         ${value}+1    
\    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${example}    10
\    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${example}    10
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users is you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).